# Jenkins remote triggers with parameters

Tags: curl, jenkins, parameters

I am running a jenkins build accross multiple hosts. Therefore I have created a string parameter with the list of IPs like:

[image]

My question is how can I specify the list of IP's if that's change in my curl command to trigger the job remotely.

Comment: Can you re-edit and explain in detail about the bottom line, I am not able to get what do you mean ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value` instead of `http://server/job/myjob/build`. More info can be [found here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build#ParameterizedBuild-Launchingabuildwithparameters).

If you have spaces in your paramater, then you replace the space with %20, so `http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?LHOST=10.4.6.236%2010.4.6.237%2010.4.6.238`

Comment: As I mentioned the parameter would be something like "ip1 ip2 ip3" how would I add that?

Comment: I've updated my answer, basically replace spaces with %20